# What is meant by a number after "break" or "continue" in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, breakpoints, break, continue

Could someone please explain, with examples, what is meant by loop `break 2` or `continue 2` in PHP? What does it mean when `break` or `continue` is followed by a number?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $item){
  if ($item == 2) {
    break;
  }
  echo $item;
}
```

outputs "1" because the loop was **broken** forever, before echo was able to print "2".

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $item){
  if ($item == 2) {
    continue;
  }
  echo $item;
}
```

outputs `13` because the second iteration was **passed**

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$letters = array("A","B","C");
foreach ($numbers as $num){
  foreach ($letters as $char){
    if ($char == "C") {
      break 2; // if this was break, o/p will be AB1AB2AB3
    }
    echo $char;
  }
  echo $num;
}
```

outputs `AB` because of `break 2`, which means that both statements was broken quite early. If this was just `break`, the output would have been `AB1AB2AB3`.

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3);
$letters = array("A","B","C");
foreach ($numbers as $num){
  foreach ($letters as $char){
    if ($char == "C") {
      continue 2;
    }
    echo $char;
  }
  echo $num;
}
```

will output `ABABAB`, because of `continue 2`: the outer loop will be passed every time.

In other words, `continue` stops the current iteration execution but lets another to run, while `break` stops the whole statement completely.
So we can ell that `continue` is applicable for the loops only, whereas `break` can be used in other statements, such as `switch`.

A number represents the number of **nested** statements affected.
if there are 2 nested loops, `break` in the inner one will break inner one (however it makes very little sense as the inner loop will be launched again in the next iteration of the outer loop). `break 2` in the inner loop will break both.

Answer (score 39):

The number just says "how many scopes to jump out of"

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 10; ++$j) {
        break 2;
    }
}
```

> $i and $j will be 0

To quote [the manual:](http://de.php.net/continue)

> continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of.

same goes for break.

Comment: I prefer your answer simply because it is short and to-the-point.

Answer (score 10):

**break** accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of.

```
<?php
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'stop', 'five');
while (list(, $val) = each($arr)) {
    if ($val == 'stop') {
        break;    /* You could also write 'break 1;' here. */
    }
    echo "$val<br />\n";
}

/* Using the optional argument. */

$i = 0;
while (++$i) {
    switch ($i) {
    case 5:
        echo "At 5<br />\n";
        break 1;  /* Exit only the switch. */
    case 10:
        echo "At 10; quitting<br />\n";
        break 2;  /* Exit the switch and the while. */
    default:
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

*[More examples of **break**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)*

**continue** accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default value is 1, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.

```
<?php
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    if (!($key % 2)) { // skip odd members
        continue;
    }
    do_something_odd($value);
}

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 5) {
    echo "Outer<br />\n";
    while (1) {
        echo "Middle<br />\n";
        while (1) {
            echo "Inner<br />\n";
            continue 3;
        }
        echo "This never gets output.<br />\n";
    }
    echo "Neither does this.<br />\n";
}
?>
```

*[More examples of **continue**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)*

Answer (score 4):

break : break the inner most  loop (exit from the loop)

break 2 : break the 2 nesting level loops (exit from the 2 nested loops)

continue : force loop for next iteration from where it is used without executing rest of loop code

continue 2: force loop for next 2 iteration from where it is used without executing rest of loop code

exit the loop when we encounter `$array` value to be 5

```
 break
    $array(4,5,8);
    for ($i=0 ;$i < 10 $i ++)
    {
        if ($array[$i]==5)
        {
          break;
        }
    }
```

break (n)

Exit both loops when we encounter value 5 in $array;

```
for ($i=0 ;$i < 10 $i ++)
  {
    for($j=0; $j <10; $j++)
     {
            if ($array[$i][$j]==5)
            {
              break 2;
            }
     }
 }
```

continue

Will print the message when value is 5;

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
   if ($array[$i] != 5)
   { 
     continue;// will reach at the first line from here which is for($i=0;.....
   }
   echo 'This is five';
}
```

}