# PHP, continue; on foreach(){ foreach(){

Tags: php, foreach

Is there a way to continue on external foreach in case that the internal foreach meet some statement ?

In example

```
foreach($c as $v)
{
    foreach($v as $j)
    {
        if($j = 1)
        {
            continue; // But not the internal foreach. the external;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you can...you have to specify how many levels it should continue..in your case continue 2; more info here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: if you explain the real case with the data and cause, you will get more appropriate answer. -1 so far, for the extreme conciseness and vagueness.

Comment: -1 as well because there has not been done much research before asking the question. Not even a look into the manual.

Comment: Regardless of SO standards, this is the top result on google. Therefore, I offer the following... This may be a code smell. In some cases wrapping the inner loop in another function/method may be a good idea.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try this, should work:

```
continue 2;
```

From the PHP Manual:

> Continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of.

[here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) in the examples (2nd exactly) described code you need

Answer (score 16):

Try this: `continue 2;` According to manual:

```
continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of.
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two solutions available for this situation, either use [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) or [`continue 2`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). Note that when using break to break out of the internal loop any code after the inner loop will still be executed.

```
foreach($c as $v)
{
    foreach($v as $j)
    {
        if($j = 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "This line will be printed";
}
```

The other solution is to use `continue` followed with how many levels back to continue from.

```
foreach($c as $v)
{
    foreach($v as $j)
    {
        if($j = 1)
        {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    // This code will not be reached.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will continue to levels above (so the outer foreach)

```
 continue 2
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
foreach($c as $v)
{
    foreach($v as $j)
    {
        if($j = 1)
        {
            continue 2; // note the number 2
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[RTM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: Every answer with a reference to `continue 2` has been downvoted once by someone, for some reason...

Answer (score 3):

Try [`break`](https://www.php.net/break) instead of `continue`.

You can follow `break` with an integer, giving the number of loops to break out of.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `break` instead of continue, if I get you right

Here I wrote an explanation on the matter: [What is meant by a number after "break" or "continue" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167561/loop-break-continue-break-2-continue-2-in-php/5167791#5167791)

Comment: No he doesn't - he just adds a number after `continue` as everyone else has pointed out.