# PHP Break & Continue at the same time

Tags: php, loops, nested-loops

I have a nested loop like so:

```
while(1){

    while($something){
        break & continue;
    }
    // More stuff that I don't want to process in this situation
}
```

I want to break out of the 2nd while loop and continue the 1st loop from the start (without finishing the 1st loop). Is this possible without using variables?

Comment: I have IF/THEN statements inside the 2nd loop that determine whether i should continue, break, or break AND continue. I could use variables to determine that, but is it possible without them is what i'm asking

Comment: This sounds more like your logic might benefit from a bit more structure than anything else; break and continue are typically last resorts to begin with.

Comment: I don't like too many nested IF/THENs in my daemons. There's a reason why I need to use breaks and continues.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to add some functional decomposition.  It'll be easier to maintain that way too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `continue 2;` in your inner loop to continue the outer loop from the beginning.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

> **continue** accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default
>   value is **1**, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'break' in inner loop. It will break out of the inner loop and the outer loop will continue.

Comment: I have more stuff after the 2nd while loop that I don't want to process. There's a reason why I need it this way.

Comment: Oh I see. That was missing in the code you posted. Did you look into numbered break and continue? See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167561/loop-break-continue-break-2-continue-2-in-php

Answer (score 0):

After the inner while, can you not just use an if statement to execute the continue?

```
while(1){

    while($something){
        break;
    }

    if (!$something) {
       continue;
    }

    // More stuff that I don't want to process in this situation
}
```

Comment: of course i can, and that's what i'm probably going to do. my question was is this possible to do without additional variables